# Clojure multimethods with functions call?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

Is it bad practice to use multimethods with simple funtions? Specifically, every method to call a function to execute the logic?

```
(defn append 
"docstring"
[[book page]] 
(.append book page))
(defmulti book!
(fn [a b] a))
(defmethod book! :append
[_ b]
(append b))
```

The reason I want to do it, is to be able to produce docstrings on each function and use the functions through multimethods.

Comment: I am making some java interop, and the first thought was to use multimethods for each java's class methods, but multimethods does not produce docstrings for documentation, because it actually is one function. So if I create seperate simple functions that will have the interop and each multimethod will call the corresponding function, is it bad practice?

Comment: Sorry for that, hope the edit make it more clear. Also sorry for misspelling 'defmethods', I am from pho e at the moment.

Comment: `defmrthod` ?  Also i think your parens at book! are wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing bad practice about having multimethods whose definition is just calling one other function. You can create as many functions at whatever level of granularity you feel provides the most readable code.

Comment: I thought that it would be bad practice to actually adding another layer and not just use the functions.

Comment: It's really up to you what you prefer to do here, there's no rule